# PHP [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory problem

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I get the following error in one of my function includes.

```
require(../htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I can correct this problem if I code the path

```
./htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php
```

But I want to display the include file in many different levels of folders on my website without having to re-code the path inside my function include every time which defeats the purpose of my include. Is there a way I can have this work with out having to re-code the path every time? Is there a way to include the full path?

Comment: Tell us how Yours Script works!
Do You have one "entry" index file witch serves all content, or stand-alone file for every "call"?

Comment: @Dariusz Górecki forgive my ignorance what do you mean?

Comment: do You have index.php, witch include dependent classes/files and using them serves output ?
or do You have one file per every page in Yours site

Comment: yes I have an index.php page but my functions are in an includes folder with there own pages.

Comment: One often runs into this error, and to quickly troubleshoot it, follow these steps : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
require realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php');
```

That way you always include files relative to the path of the current file.

Comment: You kids take this `dirname(__FILE__)` thing as a kind of a magic wand that will solve any filesystem related problem.

Comment: I get this error with your code `Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '' (include_path='C:\wamp\www\New Project\htmlpurifier\library;.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\wamp\www\New Project\includes\categories.php on line 7`

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong path.
Just put these 2 lines together and feel the difference.

```
../htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php
./htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php
```

That's 2 different paths and will never work at the same time. Latter one points to the current directory while first one - one level higher.

> But I want to display the include file in many different levels of folders on my website without having to re-code the path inside my function

that's sensible desire. Here you go:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
```

(assuming this htmlpurifier folder lays in the document root)

Comment: i get this error now with your code. `require(C:/wamp/www//htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Comment: How about posting the path to HTMLPurifier.auto.php?

Comment: @green **assuming this htmlpurifier folder lays in the document root** otherwise you have to set another path here.

Comment: my path to my htmlpurifier folder is `http://localhost/New%20Folder/htmlpurifier/`

Comment: @green well try to use `'/New Folder/htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php'` then in the expression I gave you.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
require (dirname(__FILE__).'/../htmlpurifier/library/HTMLPurifier.auto.php');
```

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507

Answer (score 0):

How about configuring the path to this .php file as a configuration variable in your script? Presumably you'll be loading some common functions library in all your pages, so just do:

```
$PATH_TO_PURIFIER = 'C:\this\that\whatever\HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
```

in that common file, then you can just do

```
include('commonstuff.php');
include($PATH_TO_PURIFIER);
```

As long as commonstuff.php is somewhere in your PHP's include_path, it's far more reliable to do it this way rather than try to dynamically calculate the path everywhere else. Especially if your directory structure might change, rendering the calculated path invalid and forcing you to change every PHP file yet again.

Comment: There is now a troubleshooting checklist for this frequent error here : stackoverflow.com/a/36577021/2873507